# How to Custer a set of spatial coordinates based on time distribution using Kmeans

Tags: pandas, time, coordinates, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am new in Python. I have a set of coordinates (lat,long) with a date which is associated to each coordinate in a Pandas DataFrame. What I am trying to do is to establish a clustering of these data based on dates, using K-means approach. Thanks to that, I will be able to implement my set of data in QGIS to visualize my set of points clustered.

I have seen some post about that, but I didn't found exactly what I wanted to do...

I have already done the clustering based only on coordinates spatial distribution thanks to the sklearn library, but I searched one for the time distribution of these coordinates and didn't found one.

Comment: You'd  better ask this kind of question there: https://gis.stackexchange.com/ ;-)

Comment: @s.k thanks but I have already seen some interesting post about this kind of things here ! Hope somebody will help me ahah